# How to start application as par fix time in android mobile phone

Tags: android

```
         I have to make one application which is start in android phone as par user given
```

time automatically.

```
          If is there any intent which i used my application to start it by user given time.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AlarmManager` class has everything you need to schedule events, and set up `Intent`s to launch activities, start services, and send broadcasts.

It is not persistent, so you must configure your alarms at system start up, either from a service or `BroadcastReceiver`.